# MySQL table relations, inheritance or not?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, relational-database

Im building a micro CMS. Using Mysql as RDMS, and Doctrine ORM for mapping.

I would like to have two types of pages. Static Page, and Blog Page.
Static page would have page_url, and page_content stored in database.
Blog page would have page_url, but no page_content. Blog would have Posts, Categories...

Lets say I have route like this:

```
/{pageurl}
```

This is page, with page url that can be home, or news, or blog...
That page can be either Static page, and then I would joust print page_content.
But it can also be Blog Page, and then I would print latest posts as content.

How should I relate these Static Page and Blog Page tables?
Is this inheritance, since both are pages, with their URL, but they have different content?
Should I use inheritance, so that both Static and Blog page extends Page that would have page_url? Or should I made another table page_types and there store information about available page types?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, and I'm speaking with a MVC framework in mind, when you use routes you would have a specific pattern that you can match to different controllers/actions that could then map to different models and views.

For instance, a standard page URL would be in the format:

```
/{pageurl}
```

Whereas a page URL for a blog page would be:

```
/blog/{pageurl}
```

This would make it very easy to distinguish between the two and route accordingly. If it matches the pattern `/blog/*`, it's a blog! However, let's assume you don't want to take the easiest method - but instead decide to have all URLs follow the same pattern: `/{pageurl}`. Your actual list of URLs should all be stored in a single table in the database, let's say it's named `site_pages`. The relationship between your `site_pages` and `blogs` would be a column in `blogs` named `page_id` that is a foreign-key back to the `site_pages` table.

With this, you have a few ways you could determine what *type* of page you're looking at:

- Add a new column to `site_pages` table, such as `is_blog`; it it's set, you have a blog!
- Every time you look up the page in the database, also get a `count()` of blog entries for the specific page; if it's `> 0`, you have a blog page. Otherwise display it as static content.
- Make an assumption that if `page_content` is empty, it's a blog.

Once you have established if the page is a static page or a blog page, you could load a corresponding Model - "Page" or "BlogPage". BlogPage can, and probably should, extend Page since they have the same purpose. The only difference between the two is that "Page" just loads the page's text-content and the View simply writes it out. The "BlogPage", on the other hand, would load the list of Categories, Posts, etc and the View would iterate through them and display them however you see fit.